# What is the rationale for using "&" selector in CSS?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

```
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX
(-100%);
    transition: tranlation: all ease
0.25s;
    &.open {
        transform: translateX (0);
    }
}
```

Js file:

```
$(document).ready (function (){
    ${".navbar-toggler"}.on("click", function (){
        $("menu").toggleClass ("open");
    });
});
```

The `&.open`  is not being selected in my code and is underlined red in my text editor (VS code) but the instructor implemented the same code it worked. Please is there any rationale for using "&" in CSS?

Comment: This looks more like less or scss,  move `.open` below the parent and use `.menu.open`.

Comment: Note you have a `{` at the end of `transition: tranlation: all ease
0.25s;{`

Comment: Oh, that's true. It's a mistake on my part when I was typing the code here but it's not actually in the one I implemented on the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&.className` or `&:pseudo-class` is basically an SCSS syntax of writing selectors which aims at choosing multiple scenarios in a className attribute . E.g. in your code `.menu` class will also have another class called `.open` class to it in `<html>` structure so this means you are selecting an element where the classname is both `.menu` and `.open` which is a way of writing nested code in SASS-SCSS, a CSS pre-processor. a typical file saved with .CSS extension may not be able to read this syntax and hence throw an error. Hope this answer helps. All the Best!